# asp.net mvc 2 + jquery mobile on android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

The web app I developed contains a drop down list, which is generated by the following codes:

`<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Subcategory_Id, Model.Subcategories as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>`

The drop down list is not selectable on android platform and I saw people suggesting to use

```
data-native-menu="true"
```

but how can I add the attribute to the code? please kindly advise.

Thanks all.

Comment: solved by changing the "overflow-x: hidden;" property to "visible" on "div.ui-mobile-viewport"

Answer (score 1):

you can access your controls by model field names 
so you can apply this tag in this way

$("#Subcategory_Id").attr("data-native-menu", "true");

you should ass this attribute on pagecreate event of jquery mobile, see the link below
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html